# Bash define vector with a variable

Tags: arrays, bash, variables, vector

i couldn't find an answer in internet for this:

```
$ echo {1..20}
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

But if I try to use a variable to define the limit:

```
$ x=20
$ echo {1..$x}
{1..$x}
```

Anyone knows how make it work? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ x=20
$ eval echo {1..$x}
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

Comment: And if you want to use it to define a vector for a loop like:

    for i in {1..$x}